# Apex code error-incompatible element type

Tags: apex

I am new to Apex and Eclipse.  I am getting the following error when trying to compile: Save error: Incompatible element type LIST for collection of Id

code:

```
Set<ID> terrOut = new Set<ID>();
terrOut.add([Select t.Id From Territory__c t where t.Name = 'WI-Brown']);
```

`Territory__c` is a custom object.  When I execute the SOQL in Eclipse Developer page, the code returns the value correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around the incompatible argument type

Change This line

```
terrOut.add([Select t.Id From Territory__c t where t.Name = 'WI-Brown']);
```

to this

```
 terrOut.add([Select t.Id From Territory__c t where t.Name = 'WI-Brown' limit 1].Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to add Territory__c to an ID, which isn't a compatible type. Instead, you'll need a means of extracting the ID values. There are two practical ways to do this:

```
Set<ID> terrOut = new map<Id, Territory__c>([Select t.Id From Territory__c t where t.Name = 'WI-Brown']).keyset();
```

---

```
Set<Id> terrOut = new Set<Id>();
terrOut.addAll(new Map<Id, Territory>([Select t.Id FROM Territory__c t where t.Name = 'WI-Brown']).keyset());
```

However, you should only use either construct if you are expecting multiple `Territory__c` records. If you are only ever getting just one, it might be better to use just a single Id value, which may be easier to work with later:

```
Id terrOut;
Territory__c[] records = [SELECT t.Id FROM Territory__c t WHERE t.Name = 'WI-Brown'];
if(!records.isEmpty())
    terrOut = records[0].Id;
```

Comment: friendly bit of advice, like Sfdcfox here has done, I think it's a good practice to, whenever possible, query into a map rather than a list. If you're retrieving a collection, a map gives you all the benefits of a list plus they're id addressable (i.e. map.get('id here'))

Answer (score -1):

You need to use addAll() instead of add(), because that query returns a collection.

Comment: Now I am getting incompatible argument type

Comment: Your original code implied that you were saving to a collection of sObjects. Now that it has been updated to show a collection of IDs this isn't the correct answer.